# How to fix MySQL storage engine error -1?

Tags: mysql

I was moving a MySQL installation from one drive to another, and once done, this problem presented itself:

```
Error 500 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine
```

Doing research on the problem presented no useful information, as much of it states that it just means the server is out of storage, however, each drive has at least 500MB of unused space. What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you move the data or the programs?  How did you proceed?